# Finding files that are Hardlink in Soalris under specific folder

Tags: linux, solaris, hardlink

I need to find hardlink files under specific folder in Solaris. Tried this below command which lists the files based on inode count.

*find . -type f -links +1*

The above command list both source and target files. But i need to list only the target_file. 
*For Eg:* Under Test folder, there is source.txt

Test

->source.txt

Created hardlink:
   *ln source.txt target.txt*

The above find command return both source.txt and target.txt. But I need a command to fetch only target.txt. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

No. After the hardlink both names of the file are equal in all ways, there is no *original* or *copy*.

Since they share the underlying inode, both files have the same attributes -- change one you change all of them.

Either switch to symbolic links or find a heuristic to choose which one you don't want to see, like it has an extension, or sorts later.